# Get back guest user osx 10.10.1

Tags: macos, parental-controls, guest-account

I upgraded to 10.10.1 and now I can only reboot to Safari mode and enable parental controls on guest user is greyed.

[image]

Does anyone know how to get the real guest user account back?

Comment: so setting it up in the system preferences users does not work ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 added screenshot of prefs

Comment: Thanks, the Guest User is enabled, but the Parental controls is grayed out ? delete that account and try again.

Comment: BTW This release is a POS. My laptop keyboard no longer works with an external plugged in.

Comment: That is why I am still on 10.9.5 and waiting as usual for 3-5 months for them to iron things out. There is nothing on 10.10 that I must have urgently :)

Comment: Have you tried editing the guest account from the Parental Controls control panel? I would imagine that you could disable parental controls (or at least make it wide open) from there. I haven't upgraded to 10.10 yet, so I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 1):

If FileVault is enabled the guest user can only use Safari because they can't access the encrypted disk partition the system resides on.